# Applescript to send email messages to the ALL EMAILS of persons with specific in interest

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email, contacts

I am trying to write a script that filters the persons in the Contacts application whose note include a specific keyword and sending those who has at least one e-mail address an e-mail (to all their email addresses). I have written the following code but something seems to be wrong. I couldn't figure out especially how to assign recipients to the outgoing message.

```
property mailSubject : "A bulk message"
property mailBody : "Hi %NAME%"
property keyword : "topic"

tell application "Contacts"
    set theRecipients to every person whose (note contains keyword)

    (* for each potential recepient *)
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theRecipients
        set theContact to item i of theRecipients

        (* get all email address of theContact *)
        set theEmailAddresses to properties of emails of theContact

        (* check if theContact has at least 1 email address *)
        if ((count of theEmailAddresses) > 0) then
            (* get the first email address *)
            set theEmailAddress to item 1 of theEmailAddresses
            (* get the name *)
            set theName to name of theContact

            (* set theBody to replaceName(mailBody, theName) *)
            set theBody to mailBody

            (* open Mail, prepare and send email *)
            tell application "Mail"
                (* create a new outgoing email message *)
                set theOutMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true}

                tell theOutMessage
                    repeat with j from 1 to number of items in theEmailAddresses
                        set theEmail to item j of theEmailAddresses
                        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theEmail}
                    end repeat
                    (* make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theEmailAddress} *)
                    set sender to "o****.g****@gmail.com>"
                    set subject to mailSubject
                    set content to theBody
                end tell
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

The execution of this script returns following error at the line `make new to recipient ...`:

```
error "Mail got an error: Can’t make {class:«class az21», «class az18»:\"Email\", «class az17» ... id:"4DE91442-A10F-41B9-B42E-DD5A16437479"} to rich text.
```

Any ideas?

Önder.

Comment: First of all it's `set theEmail to value of item j of theEmailAddresses` not `set theEmail to item j of theEmailAddresses`, which was a mistake you made in the other question that I answered and wrote the proper _code_ for you. Secondly, you are asking out of _scope_ as **Mail** knows nothing about an _object_ from **Contacts**. You could fix it by using `tell application "Contacts" to set theEmail to the value of item j of theEmailAddresses`, however you really should not be nesting one app's _code_ in another app's _code_ and then nest again the first app within the seconds app's _code_.

Comment: Telling the first app to tell a second app to have the second app tell the first app is a poor practice! It would be better to write _code_ and make use of _handlers_ to retrieve info that's out of scope of the current application's `tell` _block_.

Comment: OK, I will follow your advice and separate `tell` blocks. You say that "Mail knows nothing about an object from Contacts, in this case I need to store the name and all email addresses of the filtered contacts in data structure. However, I do not know how to do it exactly.